# Web-browser | PHP Browser reformats parameter value

Tags: php, url, browser

I have a function in PHP which redirects to the log in page if the user isn't logged in.
Which looks something similar to this:

```
function requireLogin() {
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
        $loginUrl = "https://host.com/login.php?forward_url=/dir/page.php";
        header("location: $loginUrl");
        die();
    }
}
```

For simplicity this function is called in the PHP script `page.php` located in `dir`.

Now what my browsers (Chrome, Firefox and IE) are doing is reformatting the URL visible in the address bar to:

https://host.com/login.php?forward_url=https%3A%2F%2Fhost.com%2Fdir%2Fpage.php

Well I understand that the URL parameters will be encoded, but the thing which I just don't get is why the browser is adding a prefix to the parameter `forward_url`, which is the scheme and host.

By the way, the location field in the header received by the browser is really getting to correct value.

Comment: "https:" is being added ?

Comment: The encoded version of `https://some_host.com`.

Comment: recheck what you state appears in the address bar, it has the `https://some_host...` twice. is that the correct issue?

Comment: @James I don't know if I understand you, but the correct issue is that the new location received is `https://some_host.com/login.php?forward_url=/some_dir/some_page.php` and that the browser changes it to `https://some_host.com/login.php?forward_url=https://some_host.com/some_dir/some_page.php` in the address bar, except the parameter is URL encoded ofcourse.

Comment: its hard to understand with things called "some_host.com" etc.

Comment: @Dagon I removed the all the occurrences of "some_". Look at the value of the parameter `forward_url` if you'd like to understand of course.